# Solving differential equation by separating variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac yx \frac {dy}{dx}=\sqrt {1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2}$$

I have tried like this:
$$\frac yx \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt {1+x^2+y^2(1+x^2)}\\
\implies \frac yx \frac {dy}{dx}=\sqrt {(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\\
\implies \int \frac {ydy}{\sqrt {1+y^2}}=\int \frac {xdx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
\implies \log \sqrt{1+y^2}=\log \sqrt {1+x^2}+c_1\\
\implies \frac {1+y^2}{1+x^2}=c\\$$
But in my book the answer is:
$$(1+x^2)^{3/2}-3\sqrt {1+y^2}=c$$
I can't understand how they did it,please check this..

Comment: Should we guess how you obtained this solution ?

Comment: The book is right.

Comment: Please send me the procedure

Comment: My -1 for not showing your work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have edited my question, please check this where my fault is

Comment: You erroneously moved $x$ to the denominator.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I understood my fault...thanks for helping 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:
$$\int x\sqrt{1+x^2} dx=\int \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy$$
Also,
$$\int \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy=\sqrt{1+y^2}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Rewrite as below and integrate.

$$\left(\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)^{-1/2}d(y^2)-\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{1/2}d(x^2)=0.$$

Mind the asymmetry in the exponents.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac yx \frac {dy}{dx}=\sqrt {(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$$
$$\implies \int \frac {ydy}{\sqrt {1+y^2}}=\int  {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}~dx$$
$$\implies \sqrt {1+y^2}=\dfrac{\left(x^2+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{3}+c$$where $c$ is integrating constant.